# proxy without authentication in settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am looking for a way to set system proxy settings in settings.xml. If the proxy server does not need authentication, can I leave the username and password tag blank ? How can I achieve this ?

I can not find any documents from maven on this : http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: It should work fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it works. Actually when I use the system proxy settings in a browser, the authentication happens in the backend, i.e, it authenticates using my domain credentials. But in maven I need to give the credentials additionally. I need to change my password whenever it changes which I do not do in a browser configuration. I think there is no way to configure maven to use system proxy settings. Thanks for the comments anyways.

Comment: You're correct. The Maven configuration does not leverage your browser's proxy settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a same scenario in my team. Following are our settings. Just don't include those tag in your `settings.xml`

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <port><port-number></port>
  <host><your-prox-server></host>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: If it's still not working, try duplicating the proxy definition for the https protocol.